# User model with relationship table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models User and UserRelation. The case is that User has several related users with himself(recommended by him), but he has only one person related_to(person who recommended him).

I would like to return from User object collection of recommended users and user who recommended him. I have written association for returning users collection and it works but I have no idea how should I write `has_one` association.

I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::HasOneThroughCantAssociateThroughCollection: Cannot have a has_one :through association 'User#relation' where the :through association 'User#user_relations' is a collection. Specify a has_one or belongs_to association in the :through option instead
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_relations
  has_many :related_users, through: :user_relations, source: :related_user
  has_one :relation, through: :user_relations, source: :user
end
```

UserRelation model:

```
class UserRelation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :related_user, class_name: 'User'
end
```

UserRelation columns:

- user_id
- related_user_id

Comment: Why not have a boolean on `UserRelation` to indicate the user that recommended them?

Comment: I assume that related_user column will be unique, so there wont be scenario in which two users recommended same person. I don't see a point of using boolean there. It should search through related_user_id column and return User object with id equal to user_id column

Answer (score 0):

My choice would be to put a foreign key in your User table for the possible related_to field.

If the requirement is that it can only be one (or none) then why not?

You still keep the other "user_relations" for all other types. All the time in rails, we map to the same entity in different ways.  It's not uncommon at all